# Count number of columns that meet condition

Tags: python, pandas

For each row in df, I want to count how many value belonging to column AA and B greater than 2 and save this count to a new column in the same df. So in the df below, row 0, the count =1, in row 1, count=2.
Any help please?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "AA": [3,6,0,3,4],
        "B": [1,5,1,1,4],
        "W": [1,2,1,1,9]
    })
df
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try

```py
df['count'] = df[['AA', 'B']].gt(2).sum(axis=1)
```

```
print(df)


   AA  B  W  count
0   3  1  1      1
1   6  5  2      2
2   0  1  1      0
3   3  1  1      1
4   4  4  9      2
```

Comment: they work perfectly. adding multiple condition ```df['count2'] = df[['AA']].gt(1).sum(axis=1) + df[['B']].gt(2).sum(axis=1)```

Comment: @HnV You can try `df[['AA', 'B']].gt([1, 2]).sum(axis=1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `axis=1` when using `apply()` to work with cells from a single row, but many columns.

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(item > 2 for item in[x['AA'], x['B']]), axis=1)

df
```

| index | AA | B | W | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 9 | 2 |